# How do I import a COM object namespace/enumeration in Python?

Tags: python, excel, com, namespaces, enumeration

I'm relatively new to programming/python, so I'd appreciate any help I can get.   I want to save an excel file as a specific format using Excel through COM.  Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client as win32 

def excel():
    app = 'Excel'
    x1 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('%s.Application' % app)
    ss = x1.Workbooks.Add()
    sh = ss.ActiveSheet
    x1.Visible = True
    sh.Cells(1,1).Value = 'test write'
    ss.SaveAs(Filename="temp.xls", FileFormat=56)
    x1.Application.Quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    excel()
```

My question is how do I specify the FileFormat if I don't explicitly know the code for it?  Browsing through the documentation I find the reference at about a FileFormat object.  I'm clueless on how to access the [XlFileFormat object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx) and import it in a way that I can find the enumeration value for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This question is a bit stale, but for those reaching this page from Google (as I did) my solution was accessing the constants via the `win32com.client.constants` object instead of on the application object itself [as suggested by Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646230/how-do-i-import-a-com-object-namespace-enumeration-in-python/1647147#1647147). This lets you use enum constants just like in the VBE:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
>>> C = win32com.client.constants
>>> C.xlWorkbookNormal
-4143
>>> C.xlCSV
6
>>> C.xlErrValue
2015
>>> C.xlThemeColorAccent1
5
```

Also, unless you've manually run the `makepy` utility, the constants may not be available if initializing the application with the regular `win32com.client.Dispatch(..)` method, which was another issue I was having. Using `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(..)` (as the questioner does) checks for and generates the Python bindings at runtime if required.

I found [this ActiveState page](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) to be helpful.

Comment: This helped me while I was driving AutoCAD from Python. Thanks.

Comment: You can also import it directly using `from win32com.client import constants as C`

Answer (score 2):

When I used COM to access quickbooks, I could reach the constants defined under a *constants* member of the object.  The code looked something like this (you'll be intersted in the third line):

```
self._session_manager.OpenConnection2("",
                                      application_name,
                                      QBFC8Lib.constants.ctLocalQBD)
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but try this:

```
import win32com.client as win32 

def excel():
    app = 'Excel'
    x1 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('%s.Application' % app)
    ss = x1.Workbooks.Add()
    sh = ss.ActiveSheet
    x1.Visible = True
    sh.Cells(1,1).Value = 'test write'
    ss.SaveAs(Filename="temp.xls", FileFormat=x1.constants.xlWorkbookNormal)
    x1.Application.Quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    excel()
```

Replace xlWorkbookNormal with whatever format your trying to choose in the X1FileFormat web page you posted in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no constants object for Excel.

Answer (score 1):

All of the file format constants are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx)

Comment: That's the solution I'm using now.  I've seen this problem before in other COM object interaces where there isn't proper documentation.  I know the name of the constant, but not the value.  I'm curious if there is a way to sidestep this.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule I find it really useful to pre-record any code in the VBA IDE in Excel.  This way you can find out all the values of constants etc that you need to use within your python code.  You can also make sure stuff will work from within a more controlled environment.