# pywin32.com copy only filtered data from one excel to other

Tags: pywin32

I am unable to find any suitable method to copy visible data{only filtered data} from one excel workbook to another workbook using Pywin32 com. 
I tried using `.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` ,VBA method, but its not supported in pywin32,it seems .

I get below error when trying with xlCellTypeVisible:

> NameError: name 'xlCellTypeVisible' is not defined

Any help/hint is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Python is looking for a local variable called `xlCellTypeVisible` and doesn't find one. The value of `xlCellTypeVisible` is 12 according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype). Try using `.SpecialCells(12)`

EDIT: You can also import the constants using `from win32com.client import constants as c` using the method mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413586/3249197). Then you could use `c.xlCellTypeVisible`